# Stata: How to count the number of 'active' cases in a group when new case is opened?

Tags: stata

I'm relatively new to Stata and am trying to count the number of active cases an employee has open over time in my dataset (see link below for example). I tried writing a loop using `forvalues` based on an example I found online, but keep getting

> invalid syntax

For each `EmpID` I want to count the number of cases that employee had open when a new case was added to the queue. So if a case is added with an `OpenDate` of **03/15/2015** and the `EmpID` has two other cases open at the time, the code would assign a value of **2** to `NumActiveWhenOpened` field. A case is considered active if (1) its `OpenDate` is less then the new case's `OpenDate` & (2) its `CloseDate` is greater than the new case's `OpenDate`.

The link below provides an example. I'm trying to write a loop that creates the `NumActiveWhenOpened` column. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4iyR.jpg

### EDIT

Here is the code that is not working. I'm sure there are several things wrong with it and I'm not sure how to store the count in the [NumActiveWhenOpen] field.

---

```
by EmpID: generate CaseNum = _n

egen group = group(EmpID)   
su group, meanonly

gen NumActiveWhenOpen = 0

  forvalues i = 1/ 'r(max)' {

    forvalues x = 1/CaseNum if group == `i'{

        count if OpenDate[_n] > OpenDate[_n-x] & CloseDate[_n-x] > OpenDate[_n] 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please post the failing code so we can try to determine what is wrong.

Comment: I added the failing code. I doubt it will be very helpful as I'm sure I've made a few mistakes.

Comment: The code is not necessarily helpful for those trying to help you. It is important, however, that you show that you have put some effort in trying to solve your problem. Furthermore, people may be willing to point out the mistakes, and this of course, benefits you and others searching the site in the future.

Comment: At the start of the loop, you are using incorrect quotes for `r(max)`. This seems like the cause of your error.

Comment: Just to flag that there is also a lot wrong with your last two lines of code. But the bigger (and to experienced users more interesting) question is how best to approach the problem.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Thank you for your help. This is the first time I posted to stackoverflow as I can usually find the answer and modify on my own. I'll be sure to include example data in the format you provided if I post again. I tried doing so in my original post, but I did not format it correctly and decided to remove it as I didn't think it would be helpful. I used your solution and it worked as advertised on 200k records. It did take awhile to run (approx. 1 hour) as you mentioned. I will check out the reference materials you provided. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I recommend you try @Nick's solution,  which should be much much faster.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you for your detailed response. I will test it later today. One "issue" I see is that the output now contains duplicate caseid for each empid ... although I will add a line of code that removes records with status = -1 at the end and that should do the trick (I know I didn't specifically mention that caseid is a primary key). Thanks again!

Comment: You can always `reshape` back. However, a key point is that many calculations are difficult with your existing data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a problem discussed in http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0068 but let's try to be self-contained. I am not sure that I understand the definitions, but this may help.

I'll steal part of Roberto Ferrer's sandbox.

```
clear
set more off
input ///
caseid str15(open close) empid 
1 "1/1/2010" "3/1/2010" 1 
2 "2/5/2010" "" 1 
3 "2/15/2010" "4/7/2010" 1 
4 "3/5/2010" "" 1 
5 "3/15/2010" "6/15/2010" 1 
6 "3/24/2010" "3/24/2010" 1 
1 "1/1/2010" "3/1/2010" 2 
2 "2/5/2010" "" 2 
3 "2/15/2010" "4/7/2010" 2 
4 "3/5/2010" "" 2 
5 "3/15/2010" "6/15/2010" 2 
end

gen d1 = date(open, "MDY")
gen d2 = date(close, "MDY")
format %td d1 d2
drop open close

reshape long d, i(empid caseid) j(status) 
replace status = -1 if status == 2 
replace status = . if missing(d) 
bysort empid (d) : gen nopen = sum(status) 
bysort empid d : replace nopen = nopen[_N] 

l
```

The idea is to `reshape` so that each pair of dates becomes two observations. Then if we code each opening by 1 and each closing by -1 the total number of active cases is their cumulative sum. That's all. Here are the results:

```
. l, sepby(empid)

     +---------------------------------------------+
     | empid   caseid   status           d   nopen |
     |---------------------------------------------|
  1. |     1        1        1   01jan2010       1 |
  2. |     1        2        1   05feb2010       2 |
  3. |     1        3        1   15feb2010       3 |
  4. |     1        1       -1   01mar2010       2 |
  5. |     1        4        1   05mar2010       3 |
  6. |     1        5        1   15mar2010       4 |
  7. |     1        6        1   24mar2010       4 |
  8. |     1        6       -1   24mar2010       4 |
  9. |     1        3       -1   07apr2010       3 |
 10. |     1        5       -1   15jun2010       2 |
 11. |     1        2        .           .       2 |
 12. |     1        4        .           .       2 |
     |---------------------------------------------|
 13. |     2        1        1   01jan2010       1 |
 14. |     2        2        1   05feb2010       2 |
 15. |     2        3        1   15feb2010       3 |
 16. |     2        1       -1   01mar2010       2 |
 17. |     2        4        1   05mar2010       3 |
 18. |     2        5        1   15mar2010       4 |
 19. |     2        3       -1   07apr2010       3 |
 20. |     2        5       -1   15jun2010       2 |
 21. |     2        4        .           .       2 |
 22. |     2        2        .           .       2 |
     +---------------------------------------------+
```

The bottom line is no loops needed, but `by:` helps mightily. A detail useful here is that the cumulative sum function `sum()` ignores missings.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
caseid str15(open close) empid numact
1 "1/1/2010" "3/1/2010" 1 0
2 "2/5/2010" "" 1 1
3 "2/15/2010" "4/7/2010" 1 2
4 "3/5/2010" "" 1 2
5 "3/15/2010" "6/15/2010" 1 3
6 "3/24/2010" "3/24/2010" 1 .
1 "1/1/2010" "3/1/2010" 2 0
2 "2/5/2010" "" 2 1
3 "2/15/2010" "4/7/2010" 2 2
4 "3/5/2010" "" 2 2
5 "3/15/2010" "6/15/2010" 2 3
end

gen opend = date(open, "MDY")
gen closed = date(close, "MDY")
format %td opend closed
drop open close

order empid
list, sepby(empid)

*----- what you want -----

gen numact2 = .
sort empid caseid

forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
     count if empid[`i'] == empid & /// a different count for each employee
         opend[`i'] <= closed       /// the date condition
         in 1/`i'              // no need to look at cases that have not yet occurred

     replace numact2 = r(N) - 1 in `i'
}

list, sepby(empid)
```

This is resource intensive so if you have a large data set, it will take some time. The reason is it loops over observations checking conditions. See `help stored results` and `help return` for an explanation of `r(N)`.

A good read is
[Stata tip 51: Events in intervals](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0033), The Stata Journal, by Nicholas J. Cox.

Note how I provided an example data set within the code (see `help input`). That is how I recommend you do it for future questions. This will save other people's time and increase the probabilities of you getting an answer.